# Adding django_prometheus middlewares cause 500 (server error)

Tags: django, docker-compose, prometheus, django-middleware

I wanted to monitor my django app with prometheus and I added the django-prometheus(2.1.0) and then all my requests, except `/metrics` causes 500 when `DEBUG=FALSE`. I can't understand why it's only working with `DEBUG=TRUE`.

```
    # 'django_prometheus.middleware.PrometheusBeforeMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # 'django_prometheus.middleware.PrometheusAfterMiddleware',
```

Is there anything wrong with my middlewares?

----- Update:
The only other thing which I've done when `DEBUG=FALSE` is:

```
if not DEBUG:
    sentry_sdk.init(
        "<sentry_url>",
        integrations=[DjangoIntegration()]
    )
```

I also have used `django_prometheus.models.ExportModelOperationsMixin` for my models.

related requirements version:

```
   sentry-sdk==0.14.3
   django-prometheus==2.1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not because of django-prometheus middleware. It's actually because of sentry-sdk version. This is the related [issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/661). This issue was fixed in 0.16 version of sentry-sdk, so I updated the sentry-sdk version and it was resolved.